# Fitnesse evaluate Symbol in Cell

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to evaluate a Symbol within a Cell in **Fitnesse** with C#. The problem is that i am able to evaluate the Symbol isolated in a single Cell. If I attach for example a String, the Symbol won´t be evaluated.

The Example:

```
// the ArticleNumber-Symbol holds some value but won´t be evaluated
!| DBQueryExecutionFixture |
|SqlQuery   |    
|!-SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ID LIKE <<ArticleNumber-!|
```

When the Symbol is isolated in a single Cell, everything works fine, but that is not what i need.
Example:

```
// the ArticleNumber-Symbol holds some value and will be evaluated
!| DBQueryExecutionFixture |
|ArticleNum     |    
|<<ArticleNumber|
```

The SQL-Statement would return many rows, that is why I won´t use the built in query which works fine, but is very unhandy.

Example of built in:

```
// the ArticleNumber-Symbol holds some value and will be evaluated
| Set parameter | articleNum | <<ArticleNumber |
| Query | !-SELECT * FROM Articles where ID = @articleNum-! |
```

So, my question is how can I achieve something like the examples at the bottom in the Cells of the ColumnFixture / example at the top?

Kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, a symbol cannot be embedded inside a cell's content.  You can write your own code to handle this, e.g.:

```
public class MakeSymbol: SequenceFixture {
    public void Embed(string symbolName, string content, string replacement) {
        Symbols.Save(symbolName, content.Replace("$", replacement));
    }
}
```

You could then write a test like this:

```
|make symbol|
|embed|query|!-SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ID LIKE $-!|<<ArticleNumber|

!| DBQueryExecutionFixture |
|SqlQuery     |    
|<<query|
```